# Android. Как отключить resize для фона RelativeLayout?

Tags: android

При появлении клавиатуры все содержимое `layout` уходит вверх, на размер равный размеру клавиатуры. То, что сверху не помещается, скрывается. У `layout` есть фоновая картинка, которая при появлении клавиатуры не сохраняет размеры уходя вверх, а сжимается.

Как это вылечить?

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
android:id="@+id/screen_2"
android:background="@drawable/screen_2"
android:visibility="visible"
android:onClick="hideKeyboard"
tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main" tools:context=".MainActivity">

<TextView
    style="@style/mainText"
    android:text="@string/screen_2_main_text"
    android:id="@+id/mainTextScreen2"
    android:layout_marginRight="67dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="67dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="900dp" />

<EditText
    style="@style/review"
    android:id="@+id/review"
    android:onClick="pressingInput"
    android:hint="@string/hint_review" />

<TextView
    style="@style/SubmitSteepTwo"
    android:onClick="submitScreen_2"
    android:text="@string/submit_steep_two"
    android:id="@+id/submit_steep_two" />

<ImageView
    android:onClick="mediaRecord"
    android:src="@drawable/media"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/media"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/submit_steep_two"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/submit_steep_two"
    android:layout_marginStart="30dp" />
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

в манифесте:

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
```

**Решение** 
в каталоге drawable создал xml файл с содержимым и указал его в качестве фона

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<bitmap xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:src="@drawable/screen_2" android:gravity="bottom" />
```

Comment: пробовали поставить это изображение не в фоне главного `RelativeLayout` а на `ImageView` и поставить этот `ImageView` по центру и в заднем плане

Comment: Да пробовал, при использовании adjustResize любая картинка, где бы она ни была, сжимается (если ее размер больше оставшейся части экрана). Так же пробовал различные варианты ImageView.ScaleType

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Почему бы в ресурсах не создать `background_something.xml`, внутри которого задать все параметры для вашего `background`?